# Can I include host name in ASP.Net Core route template?

Tags: asp.net-core, url-routing

I'd like to serve different pages depending on the hostname the user used to connect to the server (e.g. http://page_a.host.com would serve a different page than http://page_b.host.com).
I cannot find any information if I can somehow route based on the url hostname.

I was looking for a specification of template string format - couldn't find any comprehensive formal specification of the file.
Also I couldn't find any example of such routing.

Comment: u means you want add link to both http://Page_a.com and http://Page_b.com, and when click link a link Url will be http://Page_a.com/index? if you want to get original Url before redirect still possible.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question... I want to add a DNS entries for both page_a and page_b to point to the same server. And Route based on the request URL.